# JQuery syntax to inspect HTML elements

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to JQuery. I have the following HTML rendered:

```
<span class="activate"><label id="lblMTPrinterID1">MT1</label></span>
<span class="activate"><label id="lblNTPrinterID1">NT1</label></span>
<span class="activate"><label id="lblActive1">Y</label></span>
```

I trying to inspect the values given by the 3 labels:

```
$(function (){
var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
var MTPrinterID = tr.find("#lblMTPrinterID1").val();
var NTPrinterID = tr.find("#lblNTPrinterID1").val();
var Active = tr.find("#lblActive1").val();

});
```

These vars are all returning null even those I can see them nicely in the rendered html. I am sure I am using wrong systax due to unfamiliarity. Can some one please help :)

Comment: `label` doesn't have `.val()`. You can only retrieve its `.text()` or `.html()`.

Comment: in the dom ready handler `this` refers to the document object so `$(this).parents('tr:first')` will not return anything

Comment: As @MelanciaUK said. .val() usually returns the value attributes value. .text() returns the text between the open and closing tags. .html() returns the html exactly as you see it there.

Comment: Maybe I'm just confused at the intent, but you shouldn't need a complex line to find an element by ID. IDs are unique, so it should always be just: `$('#myIdHere').etcetc()

Comment: Thanks. Still getting nulls after using either .text() or .html()

Comment: This `var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');` will certainly return not what you're expecting. As mentioned by @Katana314, you can use the selector by ID straight away. Just make sure (and this is obvious) that your IDs are unique on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var label = $( "#lblMTPrinterID1" ).text();
```

That gives you the text inside the label tag as I think that's what you're after!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(function (){
    var MTPrinterID = $("#lblMTPrinterID1").html();
    var NTPrinterID = $("#lblNTPrinterID1").html();
    var Active = $("#lblActive1").html();
});
```

IDs should be unique for the entire page so there is no reason to filter them to be only inside the `tr` (which presumably you have in your HTML but is just not shown in the code you pasted). If they are not unique to the entire, page, use classes instead.

This is also assuming that you are doing something with these `var`s after assigning them, within the same function, because they will not be available outside the function when they are defined inside the function.

Comment: I accepted ie it is in my code. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Just had to change the .html() to .text()

Comment: You can click the check mark next to the answer and it will turn green. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code:

```
$(function (){
    /* some code here */
});
```

What does that do? It assigns a function to be run when the DOM is ready. That's what `$(function(){})` does.

Inside your handler, you are using `this`. The `this` keyword will actually point to the `document` here. You then look for `parents` of the `document`. Obviously this won't do anything useful.

I think you probably want to do something like this:

```
$(function (){
    $('td').click(function() {
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
        var MTPrinterID = tr.find("#lblMTPrinterID1").text();
        var NTPrinterID = tr.find("#lblNTPrinterID1").text();
        var Active = tr.find("#lblActive1").text();
    });
});
```

This assigns a `click` handler, so when a `td` element is clicked, the function will be run. `this` will now point to the `td` element, so it will find a parent `tr` and do the search from there.

Note also that you need to call `text()` not `val()`, since `label` elements don't have a `value`.